# How to make scrollbar in JavaFX TextArea work?

Tags: java, javafx

I declare the following `TextArea` in my FXML code, as direct child of an `AnchorPane`.

```
<TextArea fx:id="questionArea" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="49.0" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="600.0" promptText="Deze textarea bevat de vraag en de vier antwoorden." text="" wrapText="true" editable="false"/>
```

In my controller I add text to this (non editable) `TextArea`, which sometimes exceeds its height. In those cases a scrollbar shows up as expected, but it isn't working!

Does anyone know how to make the scrollbar work appropriately?

Comment: I can't replicate this using JavaFX 17.0.1 on Windows.  Non-editable text areas with overflowing text scroll vertically fine for me.  You may want to provide a [mcve] if you want debugging help.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the `promptText` attribute when `editable="false"` seems odd, and the `promptText` by itself doesn't enable scrolling. As an alternative, for a similar effect, set the `text` attribute and specify a gray text-fill paint:

```
<TextArea … editable="false" style="-fx-text-fill: gray"
    text="Deze textarea bevat de vraag en de vier antwoorden."/>
```

[image]